# Pictures in tableview change when use search bar

Tags: swift

I have created a TableView with a cell containing a label and a image. When i don't use the Search Bar everything works fine, But when I use the Search Bar picture 1.png is always showed first. Is it a way to connect the pictures to the labels when using search bar? Thanks for your help

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var TitleList = ["101", "121", "122", "131", "132"]
let ImageList = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png", "5.png"]



var filteredfarger = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        return self.filteredfarger.count
    }
    else {

        return self.TitleList.count
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.LabelTitle.text = TitleList[indexPath.row]
    cell.CellDescription.text = DescriptionList[indexPath.row]


    let imagename = UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])
    cell.CellImage.image = imagename



    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = self.filteredfarger[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = self.TitleList[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell


}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredfarger.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (self.TitleList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    self.filteredfarger = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController
        if let cell = sender as? TableViewCell {
            VC.SentData1 = cell.LabelTitle.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you search, the filtered array will only have the matched titles. There is most likely only one match, so filteredfarger.count is 1.

When cellForRowAtIndexPath is called while searching, you generate the image according to `UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])`. Since filteredfarger.count is 1, only 1 row will be created and similarly `indexPath.row` will be 0. This will result in image 1.png always being referenced from the ImageList array.

Comment: Do you know what code I have to add/change to fix this?

Comment: Using your current setup, you could move it within the the if search controller is active statement and then use UIImage(named: ImageList[find(TitleList, self.filteredfarger[indexPath.row])])

Comment: A better option would be to restructure your code to use a dictionary to associate the titles and images to each other

Comment: Thank you. Can you please show me an example how to do that?

Comment: Sure thing. let imageDictionary: [String : String] = ["101" : "1.png", "121" : "2.png", ... ]. This would allow you to retrieve "1.png" for the title "101" by using imageDictionary["101"].

Comment: Better yet, you could even consider doing something like this: let imageDictionary: [String : UIImage] = ["101" : UIImage(named: "1.png"), "121" : UIImage(named: "2.png"), ... etc ]

Comment: So I keep the TitleList and ImageList and put this code under "func updateSearchResultsForSearchController"?

Comment: The dictionary approach would be a replacement to maintaining two separate lists. Please rate if my answer was helpful and we can continue in a separate discussion since we're getting further away from the original question. If you're needing to get started on dictionaries I think you'd benefit from going through a tutorial: http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/21/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-dictionaries-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to this, so if you wouldn't mind, i would appreciate to continue the discussion somewhere else.

Comment: Im sorry to bother you, but I can't get it to work. Can you post an answer with the new code please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example of your code using a dictionary. I haven't checked or compiled this using Xcode but the general ideas are there for you to see.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

// This is an array of dictionaries
let images = [["title" : "101", "image" : UIImage(named: "1.png")], 
    ["title" : "121", "image" : UIImage(named: "2.png")],
    ["title" : "122", "image" : UIImage(named: "3.png")], 
    ["title" : "131", "image" : UIImage(named: "4.png")], 
    ["title" : "132", "image" : UIImage(named: "5.png")]]

var filteredImages = [Dictionary]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        return filteredImages.count
    }
    else {
        return images.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell

    if self.resultSearchController.active {
        let image = filteredImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = image["title"]
        cell.CellImage.image = image["image"]
    }
    else {
        let image = images[indexPath.row]
        cell.LabelTitle?.text = image["title"]
        cell.CellImage.image = image["image"]
    }
    return cell
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredImages.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    for imageDictionary in images {
         if imageDictionary["title"] == searchController.searchBar.text! {
             filteredImages += imageDictionary
         }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailedViewController
        if let cell = sender as? TableViewCell {
            VC.SentData1 = cell.LabelTitle.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

cell.TitleLabel.text = titleList[indexPath.row]
        cell.DescriptionLabel.text = DescriptionList[indexPath.row]

```
    let imagename =  UIImage(named: ImageList[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView?.image = imagename
    return cell
```